# ImageView populating dynamic value

Tags: android, dynamic, imageview

Still new to android. Be gentle. I have read a number of articles about dynamically populating  an ImageView. I need to do it in a certain way but I'm struggling with the correct syntax. Ironically, I know how to do this in iOS but I am totally stumped with Android. Below is the code.

I would like to dynamically populate the name of image resource and it's location.

```
//Set the string to lower case
String animalImageLocation = animalName.toLowerCase()+"icon";
//Prepare to set the value of the ImageView
animalView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animalView);
//Dynamically populate the image into the animalView
animalView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("R.Drawable."+<dynamicValue??>,null,null));
```

I have tried this but failed.

```
//Set the string to lower case
    String animalImageLocation = animalName.toLowerCase()+"icon";
    //Prepare to set the value of the ImageView
    animalView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animalView);
    //Dynamically populate the image into the animalView
    animalView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("R.Drawable."+animalImageLocation,null,null));
```

I have tried a few methods all of which either don't show an image or simply crashed. I need to populate the getIdentifier() with the image name effectively i.e. R.Drawable.bearicon

Any ideas?

Jeremy

Comment: Give some examples of images you want to show dynamically.

Comment: What is the name of the file in the drawable that you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `R.drawable` has no capital, which I believe matters. Also, if you pass `null` as the class, you have to provide that, too.

Try the following instead:

```
animalView.setImageResource(
    getResources().getIdentifier(
        animalImageLocation,
        "drawable",
        animalView.getContext().getPackageName()
    )
);
```

Or, perhaps this, if you prefer to pass `null` for the latter arguments:

```
animalView.setImageResource(
    getResources().getIdentifier(
        animalView.getContext().getPackageName() + ":drawable/" + animalImageLocation,
        null,
        null
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks man. Got it. I thought that .getPackageName() was getting the name of the image. I had it backwards! Thanks again!